# Is it possible to access the inner property of a JQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dictionary, properties

I'm trying to alter the **extraParams** in this plugin based on a user action.

```
var t = new $.TextboxList('#entSearch', {unique: true, plugins: {
            autocomplete: {
                minLength: 3,
                queryRemote: true, 
                placeholder: false, 
                remote: {
                    url: "{{=URL(r=request, f='call/json/suggest')}}", 
                    extraParams: {type: "", guid: ""}
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Executing the following line throws an error: **autocomplete.remote is undefined**

```
var tmp = autocomplete['remote']['extraParams']['type'];
```

Is there a way to access these inner properties of the plugin like I would reference them in a dict?

Comment: Can you define them as variables above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it as a variable so you can access it later.

```
var plugins = {
    autocomplete: {
        minLength: 3,
        queryRemote: true, 
        placeholder: false, 
        remote: {
            url: "{{=URL(r=request, f='call/json/suggest')}}", 
            extraParams: {type: "", guid: ""}
        }
    },
    t = new $.TextboxList('#entSearch', {unique: true, plugins: plugins});
```

Then you can access it as such:

```
var tmp = plugins.autocomplete.remote.extraParams.type;
// ... or ...
var tmp = plugins['autocomplete']['remote']['extraParams']['type'];
```

Comment: Thanks - I can access the values now and update them in 'plugins', but I can't set them in 't'. For some reason I cannot access 't' the same way: 't.plugins.autcomplete.remote.extraParams.type'. That's what I was attempting to do with 'autocomplete' above. Any idea why that would not work?

Comment: It depends on how the TextboxList plugin is set up. Can't help you without knowing that. But they way you're trying to access the info definitely won't work.